# Language: Python(vers3.3); If statements inside while and if statements

Tags: python, if-statement, dictionary, while-loop, boolean-logic

My program is unable to go into the last of my if/else statement.
My code:

```
def main_prog(): 
    while True:
        data_dict = {'123': 'viksun', '111': ['tord'], '333': ['test']} # Data storage.
        print (data_dict)           # Track-print
        prompt = input('Enter command >>> ').split(" ")
        if prompt[0] == 'lookup':   
            B_value = name_lookup_return_boolean(data_dict, prompt[1]) 
            if B_value == True:
                print (prompt[1],"'s number is:", name_lookup(data_dict, prompt[1])) 
            else:
                print("The name:" ,prompt[1], "do not exist, please try a different name")
```

Data struction of the dictionary: `data_dict`

```
data_dict = {'123': ['name1'], '111': ['tord'], '333': ['test']} # Data storage.
```

Function descriptions:
 - `name_lookup_returns_boolean(data_dict, name)` returns a boolean value: True if the name is located in the dictionary and False if the name does not exist.
 - `name_lookup` returns the key that corresponds to the specific name.

The functions have been tested separately from the whole program, so they are working. If you need them, I can also post them.

I can't get the program to run the last `else` statement in the program. This is going to run if the name does not exist in the dictionary: `data_dict`.

Here is the implementation of the two functions:

```
def name_lookup(data_dict, name):
    for key, value in data_dict.items():
        if name in value:
            return key



def name_lookup_return_boolean(data_dict, name):
    for value in data_dict.items():
        if name in value:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

This is the variation I have tried to use_but with no sucess:

```
def name_lookup_version_02(data_dict, name):
   for value in data_dict.values():
       if name in value:
           return True
       else:
           return False
```

Comment: If this is python, which I'm guessing it is, from the syntax, you might want to use `if prompt[1] in data_dict.keys():`.  You wouldn't need to define a separate function.  If, on the other hand, this is pseudo-code, then it's a tad difficult to help, as errors are often the result of small mistakes in code.

Comment: Could you add the language used as a tag?

Comment: How is `name_lookup_return_boolean` implemented?

Comment: This is Pyhton language; version 3.3.
Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
if B_value == True:
```

I'm guessing that `B_value` holds a true value, but not `True`. Try this instead:

```
if B_value:
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `name_lookup_return_boolean` function. You are returning `True` for both conditions. Also you should be enumerating both `key` and `value` otherwise value will be assigned a tuple.

It should look like this:

```
def name_lookup_return_boolean(data_dict, name):
  for key,value in data_dict.items():
    if name in value:
      return True
```

**UPDATE**: After testing, I realised previous answer was wrong - was only matching the first value

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But that didn't solve it.

This are an example of a program run:
    {'111': ['tord'], '123': ['viksun'], '333': ['test']}
    Enter command >>> lookup asdd
    asdd 's number is: None
    {'111': ['tord'], '123': ['viksun'], '333': ['test']}
    Enter command >>>

Comment: Did you try typing 'lookup 123' as I suggested in my answer. Also, as I said in my answer, you're going to need to provide the definitions of the name_lookup functions if you want more help, since that is likely where the problem is.

Comment: OK! Posting the 2 functions:

Comment: def name_lookup(data_dict, name):
        for key, value in data_dict.items():
            if name in value:
                return key

    def name_lookup_return_boolean(data_dict, name):
        for value in data_dict.items():
            if name in value:
                return True
            else:
                return True


And if I type: lookup 123 as you suggested the program print out: 123 's number is: None

Comment: I've updated my answer with the explanation of what is wrong.

Comment: Note, that I've updated my answer again - the previous update wasn't entirely correct.

Comment: Yes! Do not work yet but think I can handle It now. If you guys think the two implementations of the functions is correct. James Holderness, but what about the unused variable in the function, name_lookup_return_boolean ? Got a warning from Aptana Studio that the variable |key| isn't in use.??

Comment: An alternative is to replace that line with `for value in data_dict.values():`

Comment: Hello! James Holderness.
Are appreciate all the help you have giving me :) 
I finally solve the problem, thanks to your previously code.